# Why would we use a Single Schmitt-Trigger Buffer?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, output, input, buffer

The SN74LVC1G17 was used on a DIO circuit as a buffer on a FPGA. Is it used to have a higher current on the output ?
Here is the datasheet
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g17.pdf?ts=1604252447419

Comment: Please edit your question and detail your situation and what you are working on - in considerable detail.

Comment: Which way it was buffering? Into FPGA, or from FPGA?

Comment: it's typically very rare for general IO to be directly connected to an fpga pin if for no other reason than the io voltage on fpga or at least a modern one is fairly low... Also you have to start considering things like ESD etc.

Comment: @Justme the circuit is doing both.

Comment: @MadHatter Thank you.

Comment: A higher current and/or voltage at the Schmitt trigger output can be useful. But the most important is to have a clear signal. Not something slowly fluctuating.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the main purpose is to have an output signal wich is more robust than the input signal, expecially when the next circuit is edge-sensitive (i.e. you need very steep edges).

Comment: Thought I would not vote this answer up, I don't understand why it has been voted down.